# Resque workers fail upon startup

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

Resque workers won't start locally in my rails application. I enter the following command to startup a worker.

```
COUNT=1 QUEUE=* rake resque:work --trace
```

And I run into the following error. I had this working before, not sure what is causing the error to appear now.

```
(in /home/omar/Github/brooklin)
** Invoke resque:work (first_time)
** Invoke resque:preload (first_time)
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:preload
rake aborted!
No such file to load -- exception
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/gems/resque-1.21.0/lib/resque/tasks.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/omar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/omar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/omar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@Brooklin/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload
```

As well below is my lib/tasks/resque.rake file.

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
    ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"

task "resque:scheduler_setup" => :environment
```

I've added the resque.rake file to the load path by adding the following in the config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/tasks/)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: does `bundle exec rake environment resque:work` even work?

Comment: No it does not. It throws the same error.

Comment: which operating system is this? do you have redis installed already?

Comment: this is on ubuntu 11.10, and yes redis is up and running.

Comment: I've figured it out, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output statement is a little misleading.

```
No such file to load -- exception
```

Turns out I had `require exception` in one of my models, and it was complaining because it couldn't find the file exception.